# Geckodriver trying to access older version v0.19 even after upgrading to v0.23 through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I updated the Firefox for version 63 and Selenium, but I have a problem when running selenium:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession.
```

I downloaded the new geckodriver version 0.23-64, and gave execution permissions and set the path, but it is still not working and when I type the command geckodriver, it returns an older version:

```
1544545001835    geckodriver    INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1544545001840    geckodriver    INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
.
1544545001835 geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.19.1 
1544545001840 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
```

...implies that though you have downloaded the new *GeckoDriver v0.23*, *Selenium* and *Firefox v63.x* but your program is still trying to access the older version **geckodriver 0.19.1**.

### Solution

Use the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* of the *absolute path* of *GeckoDriver v0.23* binary to **override** the default *OS* variables and you can use the following solution:

- *Linux* / *MAC OS X*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=/path/to/geckodriver')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  ```
- *Windows*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  ```